# How to properly link against a static library within a subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, subdirectory

I am trying to link against a static library that I built using CMake and have a subdirectory structure to it. It looks like this (`->` represents a directory):

```
Root
| - CMakeLists.txt
| -> First
|    | - CMakeLists.txt
|    | -> Object
|    |    | - object.cpp object.hpp
|    |
| -> Second
|    | - CMakeLists.txt
|    | - secondObject.hpp secondObject.cpp
|    |
| -> Third
|    | - CMakeLists.txt
|    | - thirdObject.hpp thirdObject.cpp 
|    |
| -> Main
     | - CMakeLists.txt
     | - main.cpp
```

In Root's cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Main)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(First)
include_directories(Second)
include_directories(Third)

add_subdirectory(First)
add_subdirectory(Second)
add_subdirectory(Third)
add_subdirectory(Main)
```

In First's cmake file:

```
project(First)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

add_library(First STATIC Object/object.cpp Object/object.hpp)
add_dependencies(First Second Third)

target_link_libraries( First Second Third)
```

Second and Third are similar, but second only depends on Third, and Third does not depend on anything at all. The problem comes when I try to link it with my Main's cmake file:

```
project(Main)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(Main First Second Third)

add_executable(Main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Main First Second Third)
```

When I run `cmake ..` from a build folder, it will go through all happy and won't complain. However when I hit make, or Generate for Windows in the GUI, I will get a complaint that `object.hpp: No such file or directory`. I am including this in `main.cpp`. I can obviously change this to `#include <Object/object.hpp>` but I feel that defeats the purpose of linking into a library. (Maybe this is the wrong thinking of it).

I've also run into similar issues where in other structures like this, in a file like `object.cpp` I would need to do `#include "Object/object.hpp"` even though `object.hpp` is in the same directory as `object.cpp`.

How do I properly link project Main to project First so I don't have to `#include <Object/object.hpp>`? Or is this the only way to do it? Or am I going at this the wrong way?

Comment: Just add `target_include_directories(First PUBLIC Object)` into  `First/CMakeLists`,  to export that path as the include directory to other projects that link with First.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solution of my `CMakeLists.txt` is workable. I also think that you need to call `add_project` only once at the top level directory.

Adding the additional dependencies seems to be superflous, as CMake fill figure it out by `target_link_libraries`. I was able to run CMake and to build the project, but my files except `main.cpp` are empty.

Here are my CMakeLists.txt

**First/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)    
add_library(First STATIC Object/object.cpp Object/object.hpp)    
target_link_libraries( First Second Third)
```

**Second/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_library(Second STATIC secondObject.cpp secondObject.hpp)
target_link_libraries( Second Third)
```

**Third/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_library(Third STATIC thirdObject.cpp thirdObject.hpp)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Main)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(First)
include_directories(Second)
include_directories(Third)

add_subdirectory(First)
add_subdirectory(Second)
add_subdirectory(Third)
add_subdirectory(Main)
```